# how to configure ldap server in OBIEE

Tags: ldap, obiee

how to configure ldap server in OBIEE

Comment: OBIEE = Oracle Business Intelligence Enterprise Edition?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

http://obieeblog.wordpress.com/2009/02/03/obiee-security-enforcement-%E2%80%93-ldap-authentication/

Nice tutorial with pictures and everything.

Answer (score 1):

OBIEE 11g has a new security architecture.

Refer these posts from Oracle blogs.

- http://blogs.oracle.com/robreynolds/entry/security_in_obiee_11g_part_1
- http://blogs.oracle.com/robreynolds/entry/security_in_obiee_11g_part_2

Answer (score 0):

Specifying Authentication and Authorization in the Repository is just one part of it. You also need to follow the official guide [Integrating an Enterprise Deployment with Oracle Identity Management](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/doc.1111/e15722/oid.htm#CIHIDHEJ) for configuring the web tier to work with single sign On. There are a lot of additional steps that are not covered in the above posts and the effort should not be underestimated.